# Can SELECT * FROM multiple tables with same _TABLE_SUFFIX pattern

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, datatables

I am trying to select * rows from 3 tables that match a TABLE_SUFFIX pattern, the thing is I didn't recieve the expected output.

The query I am using:

```
SELECT
 *
FROM
 `project-id.airbyte_google_ads.client_id_*`
WHERE
  REGEXP_CONTAINS(_TABLE_SUFFIX, r"_campaign_performance_overview$")
```

The ouput recieved contains columns of other tables, and not from the ones that I want, but if I am using:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT _TABLE_SUFFIX as tables
FROM
  `project-id.airbyte_google_ads.client_id_*`
WHERE
  REGEXP_CONTAINS(_TABLE_SUFFIX, r"_campaign_performance_overview$")
```

The tables names from which I want to select rows, are correct.

My tought is that something is wrong at wildcard line, and i tought if there can be a way to use it somehow like:

```
`project-id.airbyte_google_ads.client_id_*_campaign`
```

or something similar, because looks like the query does something at FROM statement, and does whats in WHERE at a different point.

Let me know what are your toughts on that.
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Can you share the expected table names and the extra table names you are getting as part of the query result? This is so that I can test the query behaviour in my environment.

Comment: Of course Sir! The tables I am trying to combine, because they have same columns are 'client_id_2_campaign_performance', 'client_id_7_campaign_performance', 'client_id_10_campaign_performance'

Comment: Can you also share the table names that you do not want but are seeing in the result set?

Comment: The tables in the query and the table names you have provided in the comment are different. The latter has no `_overview` suffix. Can you please check these details? I was able to filter out the required tables with the same query you have provided and I'm not observing any extra columns.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry for that, i misstyped the '_overview', the right tables are like 'client_id_1_campaign_performance_overview' and so on for different number of clients.

Comment: I am trying to get the information out of all by using the query presented above. Instead i recieve the columns of other tables that are named like 'client_id_1_campaigns'. I tried without including the 'campaign' substring in the regex, but still recieve from that one, like something happens because of the * wildcard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#limitations), when using wildcard tables, all the tables in the dataset that begin with the table name before * are scanned even if `_TABLE_SUFFIX` is used in combination with `REGEXP_CONTAINS`. In our case, the wildcard pattern is `client_id_*` and hence, the values such as `client_id_1_campaigns` are also matched irrespective of the pattern in `REGEXP_CONTAINS`.

The reason for this behaviour is that, the wildcard pattern precedes the regex and scans all the tables matching the wildcard pattern and will not take the regex into account. Using wildcards while also using `REGEXP_CONTAINS` is applying regex on top of regex and is not recommended.

If you wish to have the intended target tables you will need to use the below query instead of using wildcards to query multiple tables.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT * FROM `project-id.dataset-id.client_id_2_campaign_performance_overview` UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `project-id.dataset-id.client_id_7_campaign_performance_overview` UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `project-id.dataset-id.client_id_10_campaign_performance_overview`);
```

Using the `LIKE` operator also does not give the expected results for the same reason mentioned above. The tables are scanned first then filtered giving extra columns in the result.

Also, BigQuery uses the schema for the most recently created table that matches the wildcard as the schema for the wildcard table. Even if you restrict the number of tables that you want to use from the wildcard table using the _TABLE_SUFFIX pseudo column in a WHERE clause, BigQuery uses the schema for the most recently created table that matches the wildcard. You will see the extra columns in the result if the most recently created table has them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clarification, sir! I was requiring scalability in the solution and the way  I've done it was to create an empty table that follows the schema of all tables I am trying to unify, and I used a python script that iterates over the tables and inserts the data to the empty table.

Comment: Thank you again for your clear response!

Comment: Thank you for sharing the workaround you are using :)